# Child Image and div of same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section inside which there is an image of a fixed height and a div which has some text and a background color in it. I want to make the height of the div and the image same and the div with the background color to overlap the image so that only text and background color are seen and not the image but the height should be of the image.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section>
  <img src="http://drkeyurparmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dummy-article-img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  <div style="background-color:blue">
    <h2>ABCD</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

The image has a bootstrap class of img-responsive so that on resize it shrinks and also the div along with it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` properties will work same as you want. `section` will take `img`'s height and by setting `height:100%;` and `position:absolute` to `div`, it will take same height as `img`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
section {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
<section>
  <img src="http://drkeyurparmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dummy-article-img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  <div style="background-color:blue">
    <h2>ABCD</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I need the div to come on top of the image and not on side and with should be 100%.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abhishek Pandey .Worked fine now

Answer (score 0):

Please have a link of your solution
http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/pNWpYd

```
<section>
      <img class="img-height" src = "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/28688/skotan-Thumbs-up-smiley.png" class = "img-responsive">
      <div class="content-text">
            <h2> Your text will render here </h2>
      </div>
</section>


.img-height{
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;

}

.content-text{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  padding-left:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{ display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto;}
section{ position:relative}
.overlap-text{background:rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); color:#fff; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; height:100%; width:100%;}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2a/94/e3/2a94e33f7afe6600fe9c97eda3a386b3.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>   
        <div class="overlap-text">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum dummy text</h2>
        </div>  
    </section>
```